# SQL db from ASCII to Unicode

Tags: unicode, sql-server-2008-r2, ascii, type-conversion

My SQL Server 2008 R2 database has string columns (nvarchar). And some of the old data is showing ASCII. I need to show it to the user in my site and I prefer to convert the data in the database to Unicode. Is there a quick way to do this? Are there downsides that I should be aware of?

Examples to my issue:

In the database, I see special chars instead of regulars chars. I have a name of a user which is supposed to be `Amédée`, and instead it shows `Am?d??`.

In other cases I see `&#x22;` instead of Quotation mark (`"`), or the chars `&#` instead of the word `"and"`.

Comment: How are you viewing the data in the database? A select statement? SSMS? Your website?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have accented characters in your database, it's definitely not ASCII. Find out first what codepage you/they were using in the old DB, and convert that to UTF-8, and save to a new database.

Answer (score 0):

I built the following function:

```
 public static string FixString(string textString)
        {
            textString = Regex.Replace(textString, "[\t\r\n]*", String.Empty);
            textString = Regex.Replace(textString, "(\\&nbsp;)+", " ").Replace("  ", " ").Trim(); // .Replace("-", " ");
            textString = Regex.Replace(textString, "\\(.*?\\)", String.Empty);
            textString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(textString).Trim();
            textString = Regex.Replace(textString, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
            return textString;
        }
```

and that did the trick!!!